# How do I find a camera's focal length in pixels?

Tags: focal-length, calculations

I am working on camera pose estimation. For this, I need the focal length of my smartphone camera in pixels. (My phone is HTC Wildfire S, with Android 2.3).

Comment: I don't think that makes a lot of sense, really... I'm not sure what you mean by trying to convert an optical property like a lens focal length into a digital propery, I just don't see how that translates.

Comment: Regardless of what the focal length is, the image will still be the same pixel dimensions. Focal length does not translate into pixels, those two things are disjoint concepts. Could you explain exactly what your goals are? We may then be able to help you.

Comment: You normally need focal length to do matching between 2d images and 3D models. Focal length makes up your camera matrix which u need to compute the pose via RANSAC. If you get good pose between your 2D image and 3D model then you say you have found the match. I kept my query really simple so everyone can understand.

Comment: @Nabeel: I, honestly, have no idea what your last comment was about. Matching between 2D and 3D, RANSAC, computing poses? A little more clarification would be helpful. I don't think anyone in general will know what "focal length makes up your camera matrix" means.

Comment: the camera matrix is [ fx a cx;0 fy cy; 0 0 1], where fx and fy is the focal length in pixels for the x axis and y axis. cx is the optical center of the lens projected on the sensor (not width/2,height/2, but close, just like the focal length is close to a theoretical number in my previous answer). a is close to 1.0, and often assumed to be that, except when doing L setup trinocular rectification where you need to angle the x and y axis differently from 90 degrees. PS: I used to teach this stuff at the University

Comment: Ah, the comments officially help. Though my days of doing that sort of physics are way, way, behind me... I probably would have expected quicker answer in the math stack site.

Comment: I think you'll get better results if you ask for a) the _actual size of a pixel_ from the camera's sensor (roughly, sensor dimensions divided by number of pixels in the output) and b) the focal length of the lens. You can get these things by looking at spec sheets, but they're often rounded, so you're much better off measuring and working backwards.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is really easy. Matlab camera calibration toolbox (Bouquet) or OpenCV camera calibration will do this for you if you take 10-20 images of a checkerboard. The intrinsic parameters give you the true center of the lens in pixels and the focal length in pixels. It will be pretty close to [focal length in mm]*[resolution]/[sensor size in mm], but due to mechanical inaccuracies not close enough for accurate pose estimation.

Comment: The resolution factor will be pretty difficult to determine. You have lens resolution, sensor resolution, the RSS of those two, and any other degredation imposed by the likes of low pass filters and whatnot. Not to mention the effects of diffraction.

Comment: Luckily, he doesn't need that factor to do what he needs to do, as the calibration will give him the numbers in the unit "pixels". And lens resolution doesnt have anything to do with it. Its like converting between cm and mm, you get the result in mm by multiplying the amount in cm by mm/cm . If you have 1000 pixels distributed evenly over 4.8mm, then it is 1000/4.8. and a 20mm focal length would be 20*1000/4.8 =4166 pixels, ideally, and the calibration would give a number close to that (maybe fx=4036 fy=4123), because 20mm is approximate and so is the 4.8mm sensor size, lines of dead space.

Comment: So your saying the spatial resolution of the sensor is all your care about for this equation? I'm asking because when you combine the spatial resolution of a lens with the spatial resolution of a sensor, the "actual" resolution of the system is usually considerably lower than any of its components.

Comment: It has to do with 3D geometry , where the system needs to "bootstrap" a relationship between real world coordinates and the an arbitrary normalized "unit" system. This unit is pixels. The only place in the system where this is given is by the pixel size on the sensor. the mathematical models take into account 6 factors of lens distortions, non-square pixel cells, nonrightangled x/y axes, and misaligned lenses. The fact that the lens may blur too much does not change this conversion. it just makes the image blurry.

Comment: It does not change the fact that 1 pixel is e.g. 5.5 x 5.503 um and a chessboard corner may be at position (354.87mm, 456.65mm, 3020.34mm) corresponding to pixel (305.35px , 243.745px ). And for that conversion you need stratification to the euclidean system.

Comment: A lens doesnt have a resolution because it does not convert the continuous domain to discrete domain. At the university we laughed at the naming of the new "mega pixel lenses" when they came out. Exactly because the "Mpixel" denotation of a ccd/cmos doesnt say anything about the actual pixel size. a 1/3 inch VGA vs 5Mpixel 2/3 inch vs 1024x768 1/2 inch sensor vs 5Mpixel 70mm sensor; how "sharp" a lens do you need for those? maybe the latter needs less than the VGA. Compute the pixel size and find a corresponding "lpi" or "coc" lens. (lines/circle of conf. small enough to fit within the cell).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, @Michael. Now that I understand what the purpose is, your answer makes total sense. :) You managed to read a lot into a rather information anemic question, props for that. I couldn't figure out the need for converting focal length to pixels at first.

Comment: Just to note...for any given MTF, a lens does have a measurable resolution. Assuming an "ideal" or "perfect" lens, at say MTF 50, the narrower the aperture, the lower the "spatial resolution" of the image projected, in terms of contrast. At f/4, because of the effects of diffraction, to resolve two separate white points or lines against a black background with 50% contrast, you can only achieve about 173 lp/mm. At f/8, lens resolution drops to about 85 lp/mm. As such, total system resolution is generally computed as the root squared sum of lens resolution and sensor resolution.

Comment: yes, I am well aware of how to control the depth of field and focus of the lens. I just dont mix it with the concept of digital resolution. blurring your image (by defocussing, or using F/1.4 on a lens that cant really handle it) still has the same resolution to me, the resolution would still be how fine the smooth transitions of blur is :)

Comment: I have done that. I have captured images from HTC Smartphone. I have designed CHECKER BOARD and have taken pictures of it from my phone. I then used opencv to calibrate my camera. I have got the fx, fy, cx and cy parameters. I also tried MATLAB calibration toolbox. Thanks a lot to all for your guidance.

Comment: @MichaelNielsen — I think the issue here is simply blurring of _terms_. You have a technical understanding of what _resolution_ means, but the concept of lens resolution predates digital imaging. The "megapixel lens" idea in video may be kind of silly, but the overall idea of lens resolution isn't.

Comment: yes, I realized that. it is a more general term that I initially thought. The ability to resolve in all counts.